# How can I change the visibility of CheckBox inside a ListView item, based on condition?

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating a ListView that contains a list of TextViews. I want to add an additional CheckBox or EditText inside each ListView item, based on some condition. How can I set the visibility of the particular CheckBox and EditText?

This is my code, currently it affects the visibility of all the CheckBoxes and EditTexts in the ListView.

```
 private class AdapterQuestions extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {
    private List<Question> listQuestions;

    public AdapterQuestions(Context context, List<Question> list_questions){
        super(context, R.layout.listitem_question, list_questions);
        listQuestions = list_questions;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_question, null);

        TextView tvQuestionText = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.tvQuestionText);
        tvQuestionText.setText("[" + listQuestions.get(position).getQuestionId().toString() + "] " + listQuestions.get(position).getQuestionTxt());
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) item.findViewById(R.id.cbQuestionCheckbox);
        EditText et = (EditText) item.findViewById(R.id.etQuestionMultiline);

        if(listQuestions.get(position).getQuestionType().toString()=="1"){
               cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if(listQuestions.get(position).getQuestionType().toString()=="4"){
                et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return item;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing `Strings`, You must use the method:

```
.equals()
```

I.e.:

```
if(listQuestions.get(position).getQuestionType().toString().equals("1") ){
      cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if(listQuestions.get(position).getQuestionType().toString().equals("4") ){
     et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set CheckBox or EditText invisible like:

```
if(listQuestions.get(position).getQuestionType().toString()=="1"){
    cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    et.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else if(listQuestions.get(position).getQuestionType().toString()=="4"){
    et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```